# Why get I empty table when creating hive table using hdfs data

Tags: hive

I want to insert directly a hdfs file into hive table when creating it and without specifying columns's names.

So, the table was created as :

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test10 (rec string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED;
LOCATION '/hdfs/data/adhoc/Prepublication-PUB_1EEVC-20171201/InterfacePublique-Controle-PUB_1EEVC-201711-PR-20181228-152828-indicateurs-PUB_1EEVC/*';
```

The table was created but when i want to see the data , I was empty :

```
hive (indicateurs1)> select * from test10;
OK
Time taken: 0.471 seconds
```

For your information :

```
hadoop fs -cat /hdfs/data/adhoc/Prepublication-PUB_1EEVC-20171201/InterfacePublique-Controle-PUB_1EEVC-201711-PR-20181228-152828-indicateurs-PUB_1EEVC/*
```

gives

```
DIS_CD_EFS_PSE,01,,280237,68.12
DIS_CD_EFS_PSE,02,,18621,4.53
DIS_CD_EFS_PSE,03,,76818,18.67
DIS_CD_EFS_PSE,06,,781,0.19
DIS_CD_EFS_PSE,07,,296,0.07
DIS_CD_EFS_PSE,08,,238,0.06
DIS_CD_EFS_PSE,13,,8968,2.18
```

Why the table was empty and how can I find data ?

Comment: Remove asterisk sign `*` in the end of location. When you define external table you need to specify the absolute directory path on HDFS without any file names or asterisk signs.

Comment: @serge_k, I removed but look what is the error now `Failed with exception java.io.IOException:java.io.IOException: Not a file: hdfs://ha-manny/hdfs/data/adhoc/Prepublication-PUB_1EEVC-20171201/InterfacePublique-Controle-PUB_1EEVC-201711-PR-20181228-152828-indicateurs-PUB_1EEVC/*` and it doesn't show any data.

Comment: @SA2018 what hadoop fs -ls /hdfs/data/adhoc/Prepublication-PUB_1EEVC-20171201/InterfacePublique-Controle-PUB_1EEVC-201711-PR-20181228-152828-indicateurs-PUB_1EEVC/   gives?

Comment: @leftjoin, it gives `-rwxrwxr-x   3 1EX4-sniRE bf1EX4        519 2018-12-28 15:36 /hdfs/data/adhoc/Prepublication-PUB_1EEVC-20171201/InterfacePublique-Controle-PUB_1EEVC-201711-PR-20181228-152828-indicateurs-PUB_1EEVC/part-r-00000`

Comment: @SA2018 are you sure you removed the asterisk? in the error message you posted I see `/*`. Try to delete the table and recreate without `/*` in the location.

Comment: Also the table created and selected have different names

Comment: Try specifying full hdfs path to the location including hdfs://. Like this hdfs://hdfs/data/adhoc/Prepublication-PUB_1EEVC-20171201/InterfacePublique-Controle-PUB_1EEVC-201711-PR-20181228-152828-indicateurs-PUB_1EEVC  And check this path is valid

Comment: @leftjoin, look `hive (indicateurs1)> CREATE  TABLE test17 (rec string)> ROW FORMAT DELIMITED > FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\n'> LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' > LOCATION '/hdfs/data/adhoc/InterfacePublique-Controle-PUB_1EEVC-201711-PR-20181228-152828-indicateurs-PUB_1EEVC';
OK` and then `hive (indicateurs1)> select * from test17;OKFailed with exception java.io.IOException:java.io.IOException: Not a filehdfs://hamanny/hdfs/data/adhoc/PrepublicationPUB_1EEVC20171201/InterfacePublique-Controle-PUB_1EEVC-201711-PR-20181228 152828-indicateurs-PUB_1EEVC/* Time taken: 0.792 seconds`

Comment: try to specify full hdfs path starting with hdfs:// when creating table, and check using ls the path is valid. Current path is not full URI If you have already working tables, check how the path to the location looks like using DESCRIBE FORMATTED

Comment: @leftjoin, look what i get ,`hive (indicateurs1)> CREATE  TABLE test17 (rec string)> ROW FORMAT DELIMITED> FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\n'> LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'> LOCATION 'hdfs://hdfs/data/adhoc/Prepublication-PUB_1EEVC-20171201/InterfacePublique-Controle-PUB_1EEVC-201711-PR-20181228-152828-indicateurs-PUB_1EEVC';FAILED: SemanticException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.UnknownHostException: hdfs`

Comment: Have you some working table? Do describe FORMATTED and check it's location

Comment: @leftjoin, ahah i find it location .look `Location:               hdfs://ha-manny/hdfs/data/adhoc/Prepublication-PUB_1EEVC-20171201/InterfacePublique-Controle-PUB_1EEVC-201711-PR-20181228-152828-indicateurs-PUB_1EEVC/*` . it begins with **hdfs://ha-manny/**.

Comment: @leftjoin,should I create it now using this new location ?

Comment: yes. and without /* But check it is valid and files are there

Comment: @leftjoin, i sware that I tried with (/*) and without(/*). it doesn't work at all.

Comment: it SHOULD NO be /* at the end. Location is a folder name, not pattern

Comment: @leftjoin, look `hive (indicateurs1)> CREATE  TABLE test21 (rec string)
> ROW FORMAT DELIMITED> FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\n'
> LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'> Location'hdfs://hamanny/hdfs/data/adhoc/Prepublication-PUB_1EEVC-20171201/InterfacePublique-Controle-PUB_1EEVC-201711-PR-20181228-152828-indicateurs-PUB_1EEVC';OK Time taken: 0.157 seconds hive (indicateurs1)> select * from test21;OKFailedwithexceptionfile:hdfs://hamanny/hdfsjava.io.IOException:java.io.IOException: Not a /data/Prepublication-PUB_1EEVC 20171201/InterfacePubliqueControle-PUB_1EEVC-201711-PR-20181228-152828-indicateurs PUB_1EEVC/*

Comment: And ls command shows files in that location?

Answer (score 0):

**Your SQL**

```
  CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test10 (rec string)
    ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    ROW FORMAT DELIMITED;
    LOCATION '/hdfs/data/adhoc/Prepublication-PUB_1EEVC-20171201/InterfacePublique-Controle-PUB_1EEVC-201711-PR-20181228-152828-indicateurs-PUB_1EEVC/*'
```

There are couple of issues there

- you have mentioned `ROW FORMAT DELIMITED` twice
- also you are ending your sql even before providing location. can you see `;` at the end of second `ROW FORMAT DELIMITED;`
- You provide directory location and not files

Comment: look what I get as error `FAILED: ParseException line 5:1 missing EOF at 'ROW' near ''\n''`

Comment: @SA2018 read the online documentation, understand the sql and concept,